# Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 502: Proxy Error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, endpoint

When i make webservice call to the third party server, i am gettting following error.

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 502: Proxy Error ( Connection refused )

I am able to get response via SOAP UI but not via code. I used wsimport to generate java code from WSDL.

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Have you found the cause of issue?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means that the client tried to connect to the server at an address and port which has nothing listening on it. Several possibilities come to mind:

- The service which you're trying to connect to is not running.
- The hostname in the URL is wrong, so you're connecting to the wrong host.
- The port number in the URL is wrong, so you're connecting to the
  wrong port.
- The URL says "http" when it should say "https", or vice versa.